# Latex superimposes Two columns on my Table

Tags: latex, tabular

Latex superimposes two columns in my table. This is seen between gdp2 & gdpk; and gdpk & Inf.
These make the table to exceed my page size.

```
I tried to rotate(landscape) the table, but still, the problem remains

\begin{sidewaystable}[htp]
\captionsetup{labelsep=newline,singlelinecheck=false,
    justification=raggedright}
\caption{Pairwise Correlation Matrix}
\label{table 3}
\small\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-5pt}
\begin{tabular}{lcccccccccccccc}
\hline 
       &   fdi2     &  gdp2  &    gdpk &   infl &  gfkf    &  gkf     &   scl & tariff&   minr &   bizf & trdef&  invf  &  finf&  cpi \\ 
\hline        
fdi2   &    1       &        &         &        &          &          &       &       &        &        &      &        &      &     \\
gdp    &   0.301    &   1    &         &        &          &          &       &       &        &        &      &        &      &    \\
gdpk   &    0.285   & 0.993  &  1      &        &          &          &       &       &        &        &      &        &      &   \\                           
infl   &    -0.049  & -0.082 &  -0.083 & 1      &          &          &       &       &        &        &      &        &      & \\                             
gfkf   &    0.557   & 0.473  & 0.462   &-0.069  &   1      &          &       &       &        &        &      &        &      & \\                             
gkf    &   0.579    & 0.506  & 0.495   &-0.079  &   0.959  &    1     &       &       &        &        &      &        &      & \\                         
scl    &  -0.007    & -0.089 &  -0.032 &-0.061  &   0.103  &    0.104 & 1     &       &        &        &      &        &      & \\                             
tariff &  -0.019    & 0.042  & 0.043   &0.006   &   0.018  &    0.042 & -0.131& 1     &        &        &      &        &      & \\             
minr   &    0.191   &  0.027 & 0.022   &-0.033  & 0.135    &    0.145 & -0.006& -0.026& 1      &        &      &        &      & \\                 
bizf   &    -0.109  &-0.034  & 0.019   &-0.011  &   0.03   &    0.047 & 0.431 & -0.152& -0.199 &1       &      &        &      & \\         
trdf   &    0.053   & -0.034 & -0.027  &-0.075  &   0.073  &    0.046 & 0.232 & -0.312& 0.158  &0.034   &1     &        &      & \\         
invf   &    -0.09   & -0.042 &  -0.018 &-0.137  &   0.089  &    0.072 & 0.109 & -0.168& -0.062 &0.392   &0.124 &1       &      & \\ 
finf   &    -0.121  & -0.098 &  -0.076 &-0.113  &   0.002  &   -0.012 & 0.164 & -0.17 & -0.074 &0.329   &0.148 &0.587   &   1  &  \\
cpi    & -0.137     & -0.077 &  -0.045 &  -0.08 &   -0.075 &    -0.072& 0.337 & -0.171&-0.01   &0.36    &0.044 &0.376   &0.299 & 1  \\
\hline 
\multicolumn{4}{p{.5\textwidth}}{\emph{Source:}Authors (2019)}
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

I wish for the columns to be removed, just so the table can fit on a single page, without any need to rotate

Answer (score 0):

The `\multicolumn{4}{p{.5\textwidth}}{\emph{Source:}Authors (2019)}` causes a problem for the column widths, I would simply type `\emph{Source:}Authors (2019)` after `\end{tabular}`.

But even with this problem fixed the table is still much too wide for a normal page. With a smaller font size and a different page geometry it might work, but no guarantee that people will still be able to read it..

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\tiny
\captionsetup{labelsep=newline,singlelinecheck=false,
    justification=raggedright}
\caption{Pairwise Correlation Matrix}
\label{table 3}
\small\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-3pt}
\begin{tabular}{lcccccccccccccc}
\hline 
       &   fdi2     &  gdp2  &    gdpk &   infl &  gfkf    &  gkf     &   scl & tariff&   minr &   bizf & trdef&  invf  &  finf&  cpi \\ 
\hline        
fdi2   &    1       &        &         &        &          &          &       &       &        &        &      &        &      &     \\
gdp    &   0.301    &   1    &         &        &          &          &       &       &        &        &      &        &      &    \\
gdpk   &    0.285   & 0.993  &  1      &        &          &          &       &       &        &        &      &        &      &   \\                           
infl   &    -0.049  & -0.082 &  -0.083 & 1      &          &          &       &       &        &        &      &        &      & \\                             
gfkf   &    0.557   & 0.473  & 0.462   &-0.069  &   1      &          &       &       &        &        &      &        &      & \\                             
gkf    &   0.579    & 0.506  & 0.495   &-0.079  &   0.959  &    1     &       &       &        &        &      &        &      & \\                         
scl    &  -0.007    & -0.089 &  -0.032 &-0.061  &   0.103  &    0.104 & 1     &       &        &        &      &        &      & \\                             
tariff &  -0.019    & 0.042  & 0.043   &0.006   &   0.018  &    0.042 & -0.131& 1     &        &        &      &        &      & \\             
minr   &    0.191   &  0.027 & 0.022   &-0.033  & 0.135    &    0.145 & -0.006& -0.026& 1      &        &      &        &      & \\                 
bizf   &    -0.109  &-0.034  & 0.019   &-0.011  &   0.03   &    0.047 & 0.431 & -0.152& -0.199 &1       &      &        &      & \\         
trdf   &    0.053   & -0.034 & -0.027  &-0.075  &   0.073  &    0.046 & 0.232 & -0.312& 0.158  &0.034   &1     &        &      & \\         
invf   &    -0.09   & -0.042 &  -0.018 &-0.137  &   0.089  &    0.072 & 0.109 & -0.168& -0.062 &0.392   &0.124 &1       &      & \\ 
finf   &    -0.121  & -0.098 &  -0.076 &-0.113  &   0.002  &   -0.012 & 0.164 & -0.17 & -0.074 &0.329   &0.148 &0.587   &   1  &  \\
cpi    & -0.137     & -0.077 &  -0.045 &  -0.08 &   -0.075 &    -0.072& 0.337 & -0.171&-0.01   &0.36    &0.044 &0.376   &0.299 & 1  \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\emph{Source:} Authors (2019)
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]